# Salon workers, for short?

Tags: crossword-clues, explanation

The clue is **"Salon workers, for short?"**, and
the answer is **"EDS"**.

I've spent hours trying to find an EXPLANATION for this answer.
Why are there so many sites that simply GIVE you the answer without any commentary?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and good question!

Comment: @QuestionAsker: This is not a cryptic crossword clue. Cryptic clues have two parts: a definition half and a wordplay half. This has only one, a definition.

Comment: @Deusovi I was.. so confused as first.. why would anyone have their name as 'QuestionAsker'. I thought you meant Karen

Comment: @Insane: Nope, I was talking to the person who edited this question. See the edit history, revision 6.

Comment: @Deusovi Yeah that cleared it up

Comment: Woops, sorry. I thought it was, my bad.

Answer (score 21):

[Salon](http://salon.com) is a news website - "eds" refers to "editors" here. The clue attempts to misdirect you into thinking of workers at a spa by putting the name at the beginning.